# Using Ember with a static JSON back-end

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm interested in using Ember.js to build a dynamic front-end for an app with a back-end that will essentially be static.

Is there a "best-practices" way to just use a static `json` file in lieu of a server/database back-end? This is essentially how fixtures work for development, but I'd like to do it for production (ideally loading the external json content directly into the model). Using Ember-CLI to build the app, I figure this content would live in the `/public` folder.

Ideally this data would be generated by something like Jekyll or Middleman (where a static site generator can loop through a collection of posts/items and spit out a single JSON file). I've had some success doing this with Jekyll, but the items in the JSON array don't have unique `id` attributes, which Ember-data seems to expect.

**Rationale**
I am working with academic publications (where content is published and then expected to stand for years, if not decades). If I can eliminate the need for a live server backing the application, then the entire app can be downloaded and used off-line, or in an environment such as Cordova.

Comment: There is no reason why you cannot use fixtures in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth considering something like Pretender (https://github.com/trek/pretender) which is a more "authentic" way of faking a back end for Ember models.

Even better if you plan to use Ember Data, this library has worked like a drop in replacement for a real back end.

I hear there is an Ember Addon for CLI - https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-pretender

Also, I have a JSBin lying around that demonstrates Pretender...
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nikenu/6/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is very enlightening – especially the JSBin, I don't think I could have really grokked what Pretender was doing without a live example.  Would there be any problem with using a `require` statement to load the actual data file from Ember's public directory when the pretender server is being set up? i.e. `var boxes = require("public/boxes.js")` ?

Comment: You reached the end of my limited Javascript knowledge :)  That being said,  it looks like Pretender expects to be fed basic JSON data so the only thing I can think of that *could* get in the way would be promises if they are someone added to the mix.